# how to click-through label in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, label, segue

I'm using a tablView and when a cell is tapped it segues to a new view controller, problem is a label takes up a majority of the cell and the click doesn't count if you click the label, how can I make the label clickable so it also triggers the segue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set user interaction enabled to false.

```
yourLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

If it doesn't work maybe you've got a touch listener attached to it